# How do you translate "herbarium of peril" into Latin?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, noun, word-play

Is "herbaria pericula" an accurate translation? What is the grammatically correct way to express "peril herbaria/herbarium of peril"? Compound words

This question is for a name of a work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *herbarium* is classically attested (correct me if I'm wrong, though), but *herbaria* would be correct if you want it to be plural. If it is indeed plural, then this would be correct:

> Herbaria Periculorum

If you want singular, then this:

> Herbarium Periculi

Comment: (I only know a little Latin, so maybe that is why I dont understand what "classically attested" means.) Herbarium should be correct singular nominative. I got "herbaria periculosa" when I asked someone else, but is that not "dangerous herbaria"? I am content with plural "Herbaria Periculorum" as in English "herbaria of danger" but still I wonder if Herbaria pericula would be a correct compound word when meaning two equal nominatives, a compound word as in "cat litter". If not, how about "pericoherbaria" as a new creative compound word?

Comment: Do you prefer the genitive over the adjective *periculosus*? It might be a choice worth giving and discussing.

Comment: Yes, genitive, since the herbaria or herbarium are/is not dangerous, but it is the herbaria of danger or danger herbaria. As in house of horror or horror house, not horrific house.

Comment: "but still I wonder if Herbaria pericula would be a correct compound word when meaning two equal nominatives, a compound word as in 'cat litter'" <-- absolutely not. Latin does not roll that way.

Comment: @Adam the adjective *herbarius, -a, -um* is certainly classical. As a book of plants, *herbarium* occurs in the [*Institutiones*](https://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/cassinst1.html) of Cassiodorus (died 585), which mentions (in chap. 31) a *Herbarium Dioscoridis*, which, however, seems to be a book *about* plants, with images, not a collection as we would understand the word today.